# s3 urls - get bucket name and path

Tags: python, boto3

I have a variable which has the aws s3 url

```
s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json
```

I want to get the bucket_name in a variables and rest i.e /folder1/folder2/file1.json in another variable. I tried the regular expressions and could get the bucket_name like below, not sure if there is a better way.

```
m = re.search('(?<=s3:\/\/)[^\/]+', 's3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json')
print(m.group(0))
```

How do I get the rest i.e  - folder1/folder2/file1.json ?

I have checked if there is a boto3 feature to extract the bucket_name and key from the url, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Since it's just a normal URL, you can use `urlparse` to get all the parts of the URL.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json', allow_fragments=False)
>>> o
ParseResult(scheme='s3', netloc='bucket_name', path='/folder1/folder2/file1.json', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> o.netloc
'bucket_name'
>>> o.path
'/folder1/folder2/file1.json'
```

You may have to remove the beginning slash from the key as the next answer suggests.

```
o.path.lstrip('/')
```

With Python 3 `urlparse` moved to `urllib.parse` so use:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

---

Here's a class that takes care of all the details.

```
try:
    from urlparse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse


class S3Url(object):
    """
    >>> s = S3Url("s3://bucket/hello/world")
    >>> s.bucket
    'bucket'
    >>> s.key
    'hello/world'
    >>> s.url
    's3://bucket/hello/world'

    >>> s = S3Url("s3://bucket/hello/world?qwe1=3#ddd")
    >>> s.bucket
    'bucket'
    >>> s.key
    'hello/world?qwe1=3#ddd'
    >>> s.url
    's3://bucket/hello/world?qwe1=3#ddd'

    >>> s = S3Url("s3://bucket/hello/world#foo?bar=2")
    >>> s.key
    'hello/world#foo?bar=2'
    >>> s.url
    's3://bucket/hello/world#foo?bar=2'
    """

    def __init__(self, url):
        self._parsed = urlparse(url, allow_fragments=False)

    @property
    def bucket(self):
        return self._parsed.netloc

    @property
    def key(self):
        if self._parsed.query:
            return self._parsed.path.lstrip('/') + '?' + self._parsed.query
        else:
            return self._parsed.path.lstrip('/')

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._parsed.geturl()
```

Comment: Watch out though if your filename includes a `#`, in this case, `o.path` won't contain the full key. `urlparse('s3://bucket_name/file #2.json').path == '/file '`

Comment: @charlax Is there a solution which allows for arbitrary file names (eg including a `#`)?

Comment: You can use `allow_fragments=False` for that. See updated answer. If you want to support `?` too, you can check if `query` is set and add it to the final result.

Comment: Umm... how about: 

`s3_filepath = "s3://bucket-name/some/key.txt"`
`bucket, key = s3_filepath.replace("s3://", "").split(1)`

Comment: @GrantLangseth should not it be `bucket, key = s3_filepath.replace("s3://", "").split("/", 1)`?

Answer (score 46):

A solution that works without urllib or re (also handles preceding slash):

```
def split_s3_path(s3_path):
    path_parts=s3_path.replace("s3://","").split("/")
    bucket=path_parts.pop(0)
    key="/".join(path_parts)
    return bucket, key
```

To run:

```
bucket, key = split_s3_path("s3://my-bucket/some_folder/another_folder/my_file.txt")
```

Returns:

```
bucket: my-bucket
key: some_folder/another_folder/my_file.txt
```

Comment: Probably better to use [`.partition("/")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) rather than `.split("/")` and `.join("/")`.

`bucket, _, key = s3_path.replace("s3://","").partition("/")`

Also, this is assuming that `s3://` does not appear as a substring in the path itself. No sane person would do that, but maybe an attacker could maybe exploit this? Not sure.

Comment: instead of replace, you can use `[5:]`. So even if `s3://` appears in the path again, that won't be an issue. `bucket, _, key = s3_uri[5:].partition("/")`

Answer (score 36):

For those who like me was trying to use urlparse to extract key and bucket in order to create object with boto3. There's one important detail: **remove slash from the beginning of the key**

```
from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse('s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json')
bucket = o.netloc
key = o.path
boto3.client('s3')
client.put_object(Body='test', Bucket=bucket, Key=key.lstrip('/'))
```

It took a while to realize that because boto3 doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer, I think you are using `lstrip` twice though, once when assigning to `key` and again when passing `key` to the `put_object` method. It probably doesn't matter unless your keys have two consecutive slashes. That's probably possible with s3 object names.

Comment: key is o.path, it's not included in the original reply.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoMayerhofer! Fixed.

Answer (score 24):

Pretty easy to accomplish with a single line of builtin string methods...

```python
s3_filepath = "s3://bucket-name/and/some/key.txt"
bucket, key = s3_filepath.replace("s3://", "").split("/", 1)
```

Answer (score 12):

A more recent option is to use [`cloudpathlib`](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/), which implements `pathlib` functions for files on cloud services (including S3, Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage).

In addition to those functions, it's easy to get the bucket and the key for your S3 paths.

```py
from cloudpathlib import S3Path

path = S3Path("s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json")

path.bucket
#> 'bucket_name'

path.key
#> 'folder1/folder2/file1.json'
```

Comment: I think for working with cloud and s3, that this is the most practical way! Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it with regular expressions, you can do the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> uri = 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/my-object.png'
>>> match = re.match(r's3:\/\/(.+?)\/(.+)', uri)
>>> match.group(1)
'my-bucket'
>>> match.group(2)
'my-folder/my-object.png'
```

This has the advantage that you can check for the `s3` scheme rather than allowing anything there.

Answer (score 7):

This is a nice project:

[s3path](https://github.com/liormizr/s3path) is a pathlib extention for aws s3 service

```py
>>> from s3path import S3Path
>>> path = S3Path.from_uri('s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json')
>>> print(path.bucket)
'/bucket_name'
>>> print(path.key)
'folder1/folder2/file1.json'
>>> print(list(path.key.parents))
[S3Path('folder1/folder2'), S3Path('folder1'), S3Path('.')]
```

Comment: this works! and is indeed a nice project.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done smooth

```py
bucket_name, key = s3_uri[5:].split('/', 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here it is as a one-liner using regex:

```py
import re

s3_path = "s3://bucket/path/to/key"

bucket, key = re.match(r"s3:\/\/(.+?)\/(.+)", s3_path).groups()
```

Comment: Without the backslashes: `bucket, key = re.match('s3://(.*?)/(.*)', s3_uri).groups()`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I do is:

```
s = 's3://bucket/path1/path2/file.txt'
s1 = s.split('/', 3)
bucket = s1[2]
object_key = s1[3]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Czar! Your solution is incomplete in that it does not return both "path1" and "path2".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just tested the code, and I get `object_key='path1/path2/file.txt'`. This solution has the advantage of great simplicity!

Comment: not sure how it is incomplete @line-o

Answer (score 0):

I use the following regex:

```
^(?:[s|S]3:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)(?:\/)(.+)$
```

If match, then S3 parsed parts as follows:

- match group1 => S3 bucket name
- match group2 => S3 object name

This pattern handles bucket path with or without `s3://` uri prefix.

If want to allow other *legal* bucket name chars, modify `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` part of pattern to include other chars as needed.

Complete JS example (in Typescript form)

```
const S3_URI_PATTERN = '^(?:[s|S]3:\\/\\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\\._-]+)(?:\\/)(.+)$';

export interface S3UriParseResult {
  bucket: string;
  name: string;
}

export class S3Helper {
  /**
   *
   * @param uri
   */
  static parseUri(uri: string): S3UriParseResult {
    const re = new RegExp(S3_URI_PATTERN);
    const match = re.exec(uri);
    if (!match || (match && match.length !== 3)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid S3 object URI');
    }
    return {
      bucket: match[1],
      name: match[2],
    };
  }
}
```