# Python- Get AWS Bucket Key from Path

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Given that I have something like this:

```
"s3://folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4.5/folder4.6/folder5/folder6/folder7/file_name.csv"
```

How do I parse it out so that I get the Bucket and then the Key as everything minus the last/ with the filename?

I am trying to get the path so that I can list all the files within the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [s3 urls - get bucket name and path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641315/s3-urls-get-bucket-name-and-path)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use simple [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) combo:

```
s3_path = "s3://folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4.5/folder4.6/folder5/folder6/folder7/file_name.csv"

s3_path_split = s3_path.split('/')

bucket_name = s3_path_split[2]

# 'folder1'

key_name = '/'.join(s3_path_split[3:])

# 'folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4.5/folder4.6/folder5/folder6/folder7/file_name.csv'

key_name_without_file = '/'.join(s3_path_split[3:-1])

# folder2/folder3/folder4/folder4.5/folder4.6/folder5/folder6/folder7'
```